# Validate a field only if another one passes validation (in Laravel 8)

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, conditional-statements

I have a problem, how do you add / remove a rule if another rule passed/fails?

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'description' => 'required|unique:orders,description',
        'user_id' => 'required|unique:users,id',
        'supplier_id' => 'required',
        'warehouse_id' => 'required|unique:warehouse,id',
        'warehouse_qty' => 'required'


    ];
    
    return $rules;
}
```

For example, if the **"warehouse_id"** rule fails, it would not be necessary to evaluate the **"warehouse_qty"** field's rules (since the warehouse id is not found in the db).

Or if the **"user_id"** field's rule succeeds, new rules should be activated, like for **"user_name"** and **"user_phone"** fields.

Thanks!

Comment: Something like [bail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-bail)?

Comment: Have you checked https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: You will probably have to make a custom function for this and do your own logic.

Comment: Sorry, you were actually asking about depending one field's validation on another field's result, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

To validate a field only if another passes validation, there are multiple solutions.

### Approach #2 <sup>(recommended)</sup>

Since Laravel 5.3.23; Simply move any field validation that depends on another field's rules, into Controller's `withValidator(...)` method, like:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

// ...

public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        // Skip if any previous field was invalid.
        if ($validator->failed()) return;

        // Actual validation (for fields depending on previous).
        Validator::make($this->input(), [
            'warehouse_qty' => ['required']
        ])->validate();
    });
}
```

This has the advantage of simply using existing rules, as you would normally (instead of rewriting the "`required`" rule's source-code, which the below approach does).

See also [related Laracast post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/validate-a-field-only-if-another-one-passes-validation).

> **Note** that if `rules()` method is not defined,
> `withValidator(...)` is never called (and calling `$this->input()` may result in function not defined error).

### Approach #1 <sup>(Old answer)</sup>

Since Laravel 5.6 and later we can do below:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

// ...

public function rules()
{
    $result = [
        // ...
        'warehouse_id' => 'required|unique:warehouse,id',
    ];

    if (Validator::make($this->input(), $result)->passes()) {
        $result['warehouse_qty'] = [
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (empty($value)) {
                    $fail('The '.$attribute.' is required.');
                }
            },
        ];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

> **Note** that for above to work, the fields order is important, and the `closure` should be added to array right after the fields it is depending on.

-------===-------

While above are custom approaches (for asked matter), doing that for rules of the **same** field is built-in Laravel.

1. Adding a rule if another rule passed is easy:

   - The rules are executed from left to right.
   - Use pipe (the `|` character) to separate rules.
   - And, as long as rules at left pass, the later rules are added and/or executed.
2. Removing a rule if another rule fails can be achieved by pipe as well.

   > Simply because any rule after the failed one is ignored.
3. But the reverse of above two statements is not possible:

   - We can not add and/or execute next-rule if previous fails.
   - We can not remove next-rule if previous passed.
   - At least, not without custom function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who gave their solutions to my problem, especially Top-Master, since his explanation showed me another point of view.

I was finally able to solve my problem, and this is my solution. If anyone can improve the code, it is welcome.

```
public function rules()
{   

    $rules = [
        'description' => 'required|unique:orders,description',
        'user_id' => 'required|unique:users,id',
        'supplier_id' => 'required'
    ];
  
    $rules = $this->validateItems($rules);
    
    return $rules;
}

public function validateItems($rules){


        $rules["warehouse_id"] = ['required', 
                                  'unique:warehouse,id'];
        
        //Here I validate if the rules of the "warehouse_id" field fail or not.
        $validator = Validator::make($this->input('warehouse_id'), [
            "id" => ['required', 
                     'unique:warehouse,id']
        ]);

        //If the validation doesn't fail, the "warehouse_qty" field is added to $rule                                 
        if(!($validator->fails())){
            $rules["warehouse_qty"] = ['required'];
        }
        
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: See my Approach #2 which like your answer has the advantage of directly using rules (like `required`) without re-writing them (but without your answers disadvantages).

Comment: Disadvantages: you are copying and running  `warehouse_id` field's rules (which is not done by my Approach #2), also, Laravel will redo it (making your code little slower).